# ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END when executing query with MySQL2 running on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, data-access-layer, mysql2

I'm implementing a functionality which should upon a click on a button extend an user session lifespan by sending a request to the backend and to update the database using [MySQL2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).

In order to do that I wrote the following front-end code:

```js
onClose: function (oAction) {
    try {
        if (oAction == "YES") {
            let reqURL = "/sessionExtend";
            let reqData = {
                session_id: sessionStorage.getItem("SessionId"),
                user_id: sessionStorage.getItem("UserId")
            };
            let callbackOK = function (responseData) {
                curr.onSuccessfulResponse(curr, responseData, "sessionExtendSuccess", "sessionExtendFail", "", false);
            };
            let callbackErr = function (responseData) {
                curr.onErrorResponse(curr, responseData, "sessionExtendFail");
            };

            curr.performRequest(reqURL, reqData, callbackOK, callbackErr);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        MessageToast.show(sMsg);
    }
}
```

The request is received by app.js, which establishes the database connection using MySQL2 and forwards the request to the DAL:

```js
app.post("/sessionExtend", async function (req, res) {

    let session_id = req.body.session_id;
    let user_id = req.body.user_id;

    let con = DAL.getConnection();

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    try {

        const response = await DAL.sessionExtend(con, session_id, user_id);

        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "result": true,
            "message": "session extended"
        }));

    } catch (e) {

        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "result": false,
            "message": "can not extend session"
        }));

    }

    con.close();

});
```

The DAL module executes the SQL-query and should return the result either success or error:

```js
sessionExtend: async function sessionExtend(con, session_id, user_id) {

    con.connect(function (err) {
        try {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.query(qryDict.SQL_QUERIES.setUpdateExtendSession, [session_id, user_id], function (err) {

                let result;

                if (err) {
                    result = JSON.stringify({
                        "result": false,
                        "message": "failure"
                    });
                } else {
                    result = JSON.stringify({
                        "result": true,
                        "message": "success"
                    });
                }

                return result;

            });
        } catch (err) {
            let result = JSON.stringify({
                "result": false,
                "message": err
            });

            return result;
        }
    });
},
```

The problem is that when I execute this code in debugger, I get an exception:

> ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write
> after end
> at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:297:11)
> at Connection.write (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:226:17)
> at Connection.writePacket (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:271:12)
> at ClientHandshake.sendCredentials (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\client_handshake.js:64:16)
> at ClientHandshake.handshakeInit (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\client_handshake.js:137:12)
> at ClientHandshake.execute (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:39:22)
> at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:417:32)
> at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
> at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
> at Socket. (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\TST\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)

I also paid attention that during the debugging, I firstly get on a frontend a response from the backend and only then I reach the breakpoints in DAL withing `con.query(qryDict.SQL_QUERIES.setUpdateExtendSession, [session_id, user_id], function (err) {…}`.

My questions:

1. Why do I get `ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END` and how to avoid it?
2. Why do I firstly get on the frontend a response from the backend and only then I reach the breakpoints in DAL? I assumed that `await DAL.sessionExtend(con, session_id, user_id)` should wait until the task on a DAL will be done and a promise will be resolved.

Comment: You are not waiting for your con.connect and con.query calls. If your SQL library has a promise interface, use that and `await` it. Otherwise use `require('util').promisify` to turn it into one.

Comment: And the write after stream end happens because you execute con.close before con.query even ran.

Comment: @CherryDT, I assumed something similar regarding `DAL.getConnection()`, which wraps the `createConnection(…)` of MySQL2, I'll check `require('util').promisify`. Regarding `con.query(…)`, I use a callback, which should be reached when the query is done.

Comment: Yes but your sessionExtend function has long returned at the point that that callback gets executed. See my answer below

Comment: Oops I saw only now that you specified that you are using MySQL2. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short**: You are not awaiting the `con.connection` and `con.query`, so the outer code continues and calls `con.close` and returns the frontend result, and later on `con.query` attempts to send a query through the now-closed connection, leading to this exception.

You are writing async functions but you only made them "half-async".

For example, this won't work:

```js
async function getStuff () {
  stuff.get(function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err // kills your process if it happend!
    return data.stuff // returns to nowhere
  })
}

// later on:
const stuff = await getStuff()
console.log(stuff) // prints undefined!
```

...because essentially, your async function just synchronously calls another function( not waiting for it) then immediately returns nothing (i.e. `undefined`):

```js
async function getStuff () {
  stuff.get(...)
  // as you can see, no return inside getStuff
}
```

And later on, the callback you passed will run, but then your outer code's train has already left the platform.

What you'd want to do instead is have `stuff.get` return a promise (most modern libraries will do that even if they additionally expose a callback promise for compatibility with older codebases) and `await` it:

```js
async function getStuff () {
  const data = await stuff.get() // waits for the stuff to come back
  return data.stuff // actually returns the stuff
  // The `if (err) throw err` now became unnecessary as well
}

// later on:
const stuff = await getStuff()
console.log(stuff) // prints the stuff!
```

If your SQL library would expose a promise interface, you could simply `await` it. You wrote that you are using `mysql2`. This library has a promise interface if required with `require('mysql2/promise')`. I'd suggest switching to the promise interface instead of the callback interface!

There is also a way to "upgrade" an existing `con` connection to the promise interface: `con.promise()`. So you'd simply do `con = DAL.getConnection().promise()` instead of `con = DAL.getConnection()`.

Then, you could rewrite the code like this (or equivalent, depending on which library you pick):

```js
async function sessionExtend(con, session_id, user_id) {
    try {
        await con.connect()
        await con.query(qryDict.SQL_QUERIES.setUpdateExtendSession, [session_id, user_id])
        return JSON.stringify({ result: true, message: 'success' })
    } catch (err) {
        return JSON.stringify({ result: false, message: err.toString() })
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** *The following part is actually obsolete because `mysql2` allows upgrading an existing connection to the promise interface, but I'll leave this here anyway in case it helps someone else in a similar situation!*

If you can't switch to the promise interface, you could instead promisify the existing calls (it just looks a bit more convoluted though):

```js
const { promisify } = require('util')

async function sessionExtend(con, session_id, user_id) {
    try {
        await promisify(con.connect).call(con)
        await promisify(con.query).call(con, qryDict.SQL_QUERIES.setUpdateExtendSession, [session_id, user_id])
        return JSON.stringify({ result: true, message: 'success' })
    } catch (err) {
        return JSON.stringify({ result: false, message: err.toString() })
    }
}
```

`util.promisify` wraps a function that expects an `(err, data)` callback, converting it into an async function that returns a promise instead. Since `con.query` et al. are methods on `con` though, they need to keep that context, that's why I wrote `promisify(con.query).call(con, ...)` instead of just `promisify(con.query)(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I'm using [MySQL2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) and in their code snippets of connection establishment there is no any mention that promises are mandatory.

Comment: They aren't. But if you don't use them, you'd have to use callbacks throughout, which you aren't doing (that's why the code isn't working). And if you did, the code would work but it would also become more convoluted. It's just like paying your subscriptions with credit card is probably not always _mandatory_, but it is very helpful, because otherwise you have the hassle of paying in cash every month. ;)

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the options that exist with MySQL2

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed explanation and pointing out to the [`mysql2/promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper), that really allows to get rid of the callback hell and to keep the code clean and clear.

Answer (score 2):

With a help of **CherryDT**, the problem has been solved by switching to ES7 `async`/`await`-wrapper version of MySQL2 — [**`mysql2/promise`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper).

To save a time of the rest of the public, the final ready-to-use code:

**app.js**

```js
app.post("/sessionExtend", async function (req, res) {

    let session_id = req.body.session_id;
    let user_id = req.body.user_id;

    const con = await DAL.getConnection();

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    const response = await DAL.sessionExtend(con, session_id, user_id);

    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "result": response.result,
        "message": response.message
    }));

    await con.close();

});
```

**DAL.js**

```js
sessionExtend: async function sessionExtend(con, session_id, user_id) {

    let result;

    const [rows, fields] = await con.execute(qryDict.SQL_QUERIES.setUpdateExtendSession, [session_id, user_id]);

    if (rows.warningStatus === 0) {
        result = {
            "result": true,
            "message": "session extended"
        };
    } else {
        result = {
            "result": false,
            "message": "session is not extended"
        };
    }

    return result;

},
```

As you may see, now the code is a way easier to understand and maintain.

P.S. My advise: use the `async`/`await`, they are wonderful and try to avoid callbacks as much as possible.